# Fill png image with certain number of points

Tags: c#, algorithm, bitmap, png

I'm working to a software that need a strange feature. I choose a png image like image attached and I need to place uniformly a certain number of points on black surface. I started with loop each pixel and change it's color to black, only for design, but now I need to think an algorithm to fill it with points (like 200 points (pixels with red color). You have a idea how to do this ?

Now in my mind is to count black pixels, then do something like this blackPixelsPerPoint = blackPixels / numberOfPoints. After this I now i need to have a red point every blackPixelsPerPoint.

[image: Logo after fill pixels with black]

The result need to be something like N letter
[image: Result]

The points need to have almost same space between them and fill all the black surface if is possible (depend by number of points).

Comment: Can u also attach the expected resultant image with the code you have tried.

Comment: And what have u tried to do that

Comment: My code do almost nothing now, but i'm trying to improve it a bit and post it here

Comment: The result image is made with photoshop

Comment: This is a very unclear question. Much depends upon what you mean by "uniform". If you mean uniform relative to an external grid of uniformly placed points, then that's a big challenge due to the geometries of the letters vs. the grid. If you mean relative to each letter, then the dots won't be uniformly spaced relative to each other. It looks like you're placing 5 dots on each long line, except for some with 4 dots, and none on the short lines. That's not uniform. You need to be much clearer on what you want to achieve